# If the limit exists, find it, otherwise, prove it does not exist

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} (1+3x^2+3y^2)^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+2x^2y^2}}$

$t=x^2+y^2$ is no good as it doesn't really help with the $2x^2y^2$ factor in the exponent.

I then try using e and ln:

$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} (1+3x^2+3y^2)^{e^{\ln(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+2x^2y^2})}}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} (1+3x^2+3y^2)^{e^{-\ln({x^2+y^2+2x^2y^2})}}$

But I haven no idea what I can do next, I should add that I did not try polar coordinates as I couldn't see how we get away from the problem that if r goes to 0, then the exponent goes to 1/0 which is division by zero.

Comment: Try using the $e$ and $\ln$ trick on the whole expression, and then using the continuity of $e^x.$ Then you might be able to combine that with your polar coordinates idea.

Comment: I have an answer prepared, but I think it would be good for you to try again. Can you let me know how any new attempts go?

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested, using e and ln on the whole expressions gives us:

$\displaystyle e^{\frac{\ln(1+3x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2+2x^2y^2}}$ and the exponent evaluates to 3. I tried introducing polar coordiantes which with a little simplification gives:
(everything with base e, of course): $\dfrac{\ln(1+3r^2)}{r^2(1+r^2\sin^2(\theta) \cos^2(\theta)}$, But I'm not too sure where to go from here. Maybe l'hopital's rule but it looks like it'll get messy, I'm sure I'm missing something.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you say about the exponent evaluating to $3,$ it looks like $0/0$ to me whether you introduce polar coordinates or not. In either case, I did end up doing L'Hospital's rule, there may be something better but it really isn't that bad. (I'll release my answer since you got the major ideas)

Comment: I meant that the exponent of e evaluates to 3, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting in polar form:

$$\lim_{r \to 0} (1 + 3r^2)^{\frac{1}{r^2 + 2r^4\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)}}$$

Now try rewriting the *whole* expression using $x = e^{\ln(x)}$:

$$\lim_{r \to 0} e^{\frac{1}{r^2 + 2r^4\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)}\cdot\ln(1 + 3r^2)}$$

By the continuity of $e^x,$ we can rewrite this as $e^L,$ where

$$L = \lim_{r \to 0}\frac{\ln(1 + 3r^2)}{r^2 + 2r^4\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)}$$

Now notice that our limit is of the form $0/0.$ This means we can use L'Hospital's rule:

$$L = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\frac{6r}{1 + 3r^2}}{2r + 8r^3\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)} = \lim_{r \to 0}\frac{6r}{6r^3 + 24r^5\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta) + 2r + 8r^3\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)}$$

Reapplying L'Hospital's rule (as our limit is still of the form $0/0$) yields

$$L = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{6}{18r^2 + 120r^4\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta) + 2 + 24r^2\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)} = \lim_{r\to0} \frac{6}{2 + o(r)} = 3.$$

Our original limit has the value $e^L,$ so our final answer is $\boxed{e^3.}$